# MixRasch package -person parameter

Tags: r, parameters

I am using the MixRasch package, inputing a 2597 by 10 matrix, but the program estimates only 2592 persons. There are no missing values in the original matrix, I cannot understand why some lines are dropped.

Can some mixRasch user help me figure this out?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? Preferably with some simulated dataset and the code that demonstrates the behavior you're observing on your real dataset?

Comment: Yes, please do provide more details from your model, parameters and data.